# How to create a new Rails 3 project in aptana 3? and also turn the perspective to the rails or ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana

I have aptana 3 and is updated.
How to create a new project and setup a server for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the doc on creating Rails project and starting a server in Aptana Studio 3: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Rails+Development.  There is no Rails or Ruby specific perspective any more, just the Web perspective.  Also some of the Rails specific views in RadRails 2 are deprecated, as there is now a built-in Terminal view where the rails commands could be run.